# Defining the contents of a URL

Tags: url-scheme

I have a web site which contains forms for my customers to download. They are constantly telling me that the %20 listed in the url when they are looking at a form means there is a 20% discount on the items listed on the form. The following url is what is displayed in one example. Can you explain to me what the %20 means in this url? http://www.schumachersuniforms.com/form/Atonement%20PreK.pdf

Comment: You can get the details here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: %20 is the url encoding for space (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Answer (score 2):

## Percent Encoding

A [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) cannot contain certain characters. The [SPACE character](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)) is one of the those forbidden chapters.

Your [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) document is apparently named with a SPACE in the middle, `Atonement PreK.pdf`.

[Percent Encoding](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), also known as URL Encoding, is a way to replace the offending characters with a sequence of other characters. That sequence begins with a [PERCENT SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0025/index.htm) character. A [hexadecimal](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) number of the character’s [code point](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) follows.

The decimal [code point for SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20/index.htm) is 32, the hex is 20. So the string `%20` substitutes for the SPACE.

No way around this:

- If you really don't want the `%20`, then avoid naming your PDF document with space characters. Example: `AtonementPreK.pdf`.
- Or use a more sophisticated web scheme for handling the URL triggering a download other than directly referencing the file name.

Do not confuse URL encoding with [HTML (and XML) character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).